# In Androd, if we have two network interfaces (wlan, ppp), how to route the packets from/to wlan to ppp

Tags: android

from android, over serial/UART, connected to another device and running ppp between them. ppp between two nodes are works fine when wifi/ethernet is not enabled on andorid. as soon as wifi/ethernet is enabled on the android, ping is not working between nodes. I want to use device 1's internet sharing with device 2 over PPP.

Comment: Can you also include which process you have tried. The question is too broad. Please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to run pppd command from root shell on the device(android). did the same thing on the other side(linux device).